# PROLOG get name through condition

Tags: prolog

I am stuck with the conditional or query to get the name of a student which age must be over "25" and teacher must be "jdoe".

I want a condition which takes 2 parameters (age, teacher). Such as:

```
?-find(26, jdoe).
```

My Prolog code looks like this:

```
/*student(name,studnumb,age,sex)*/

student(cax,1234,22,female).
student(sad,7839,26,male).
student(fads,1726,29,male).
student(rafa,1114,25,male).
student(gafrh,6654,36,female).
student(reads,4627,20,male).
student(hyqa,2563,25,female).
student(berat,9258,30,female).

find(S1, S2):-
    S1 > 25,
    S2 == jdoe,
    write(student(, _, S1, _)).

takes(1234,1111).
takes(7839,1111).
takes(1726,1111).
takes(1114,2345).
takes(6654,1111).
takes(4627,4588).
takes(2563,2222).
takes(9258,6534).

teaches(jdoe,1111).
teaches(bbuilder,2345).
teaches(tkailor,6789).
teaches(jdough,4588).
teaches(krain,2222).
teaches(slisterine,6534).
```

Unfortunately, I can **not** achieve the right **query or conditional** to print the right group of student names which are over "25" and have "jdoe" as a teacher.

Comment: You should use meaningful variables. What's `S1` and `S2`? Why not, `find_student(MinAge, Teacher, Student) :- ...`? You need the `Student` argument to "return" student names in. Don't use `write`. `write(student(, _, S1, _)).` does not run a query on `student`. It will just write out the term `student(, _, S1, _)`. I'm a little confused about the age. Are you passing the minimum age as the argument? Or are you supposed to check for age over 25 hard-coded in the predicate? If you're checking for 25 in the predicate, what's the point of the age argument?

Comment: If you query the student data, you can do so with `student(StudentName, StudentId, Age, _)` (if you don't care about gender). You need the `Age` to check against minimum age, you need the name to display as a result, and you need the student Id to look up subjects. With this, you can now enforce the condition, `Age > MinAge`, and you can get a subject Id using `takes(StudentId, SubjectId)`. Finally, you can check for `teaches(Teacher, SubjectId)`. These are all of the conditions that will give the resulting `StudentName` that you want.

Comment: More succinctly: your predicate `find/2` needs to call the database predicates to get the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think next code.

```
find(YO, TN):-
  student(SN, IS, SY, SX),
  (var(YO)->true
  ;SY > YO),
  takes(IS, IT),
  teaches(TN,IT),
  writeln([TN,student(SN,IS,SY,SX)]),fail;true.
```

I try next test code.

```
main:-  
  find(25,jdoe),
  find(20,krain).
[jdoe,student(sad,7839,26,male)]
[jdoe,student(fads,1726,29,male)]
[jdoe,student(gafrh,6654,36,female)]
[krain,student(hyqa,2563,25,female)]
```

Comment: Nice!! It worked.

I am using your logic to a similar exercise, I may need your help again :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060740/prolog-conditional-function

Comment: I like the simple code of prolog look like SQL. Thanks!.