# PROLOG - conditional function

Tags: prolog

How can I list list the **names** of courses having both male and female students registered for them.

**CODE:**

```
/*student(name,studnumb,age,sex)*/ 
student(braum,1234,22,male).
student(lux,7839,26,female).
student(ekko,1726,29,male).
student(kayle,1114,25,female).
student(darius,6654,36,male).
student(morgana,4627,20,female).
student(ashe,2563,25,female).
student(brand,9258,30,male).

findboys(GENDER):-
   student(_, IS, SY, GENDER),
   (  var(GENDER)->true
   ;  SY = male
   ),
   takes(IS, IT),
   teaches(TN,IT),
   writeln([TN,course(IS, _)]),
   fail
;  true.

/*takes(studnum,modnum)*/  
takes(1234,1111).
takes(7839,1111).
takes(1726,1111).
takes(1114,2345).
takes(6654,1111).
takes(4627,4588).
takes(2563,2222).
takes(9258,6534).

/*course(modnum,modname)*/ 
course(2222,maths).
course(2345,english).
course(1111,computerscience).
course(6654,spanish).
course(6789,antrophormism).
course(4588,teology).
```

Unfortunately, I can **not** achieve the right **query or conditional** to print the list the **names** of courses having both male and female students registered for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Prolog, think of it as a logical statement:

> `C` is a class with both male and female students *if* has_male_students(C) and has_female_students(C)

You can write that as follows, thinking of the `:-` operator as the *if*:

```
has_both_mf(C) :- has_gender(C, male), has_gender(C, female).
```

Now you just have to figure the logic for a class having a specific gender:

> `C` has gender `G` students *if* `C` has id `CourseId`, student Id takes course `CourseId` and student Id is gender `G`.

You can write that as:

```
has_gender(C, G) :-
    course(CourseId, C),
    takes(StudentId, CourseId),
    student(_, StudentId, _, G).
```

Now you're going to get repeats because a class may have multiple casts of male and female students, so a given class solves the same logic in more than one way. I'll leave that as an exercise to get unique solutions. An easy way is to use the `once/1` predicate in SWI Prolog (you can find it in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. I am understanding it perfectly.

I tried to implement the same logic for another exercise. Althous some issues are presented:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072485/prolog-complex-function-conditional

Comment: @CarlosRoldan that's great. On that other question, you should edit the question and show what you tried and where you are stuck or what problem you're encountering. That will make it a better question. If people here sense that you're just looking for someone to do your homework for you, you'll get down-votes and the question will get closed. So it's best to show your work and be as specific as possible.